# The Divi blurb module sometimes doesn't go to 100% the height of the row?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, divi

I use Divi blurb modules quite a bit, e.g here: https://tianyiconsulting.claire-nicholson.com/lead-generation-qualification/ - at the top of the page, under the header.

I am struggling to get them the same height. The 'database generation' module looks shorter than the others.

I set the following CSS on the blurb modules themselves:
`min-height:100%; max-height:100%; height:100%;` 
And on the row, 'equalise column heights', but I always get one or two columns that aren't quite the same height.

Can anyone tell me how I fix this?
This is what I'm trying to do, but it never works: https://diviextended.com/documentation/divi-blurb-extended/how-to-set-the-blurbs-of-equal-height/

Answer (score 0):

on visual builder, try to change 400px to 360px custom view, and set it all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).